# Merge two dataframes in R when cells itself contain dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I currently have two dataframes with the same columns and column names and would like to merge them using rbind(). However, when attempting to do so, R throws the error

> Error in rownames(value[[jj]])[ri] <- rownames(xij) : 
>    replacement has length zero

The problem seems to be that one column within these dataframes itself contains a dataframe in each cell. While this is no problem for data storage, it seems to be one when merging data.

Any idea how to solve this?

So far, I tried rbind(df1, df2) as well as bind_rows(df1, df2) from the dplyr package. None of these worked.

```r
rbind(df1, df2)

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of your data frame

Answer (score 0):

```
# Add datasets vertically
rbind(dataset1, dataset2)

# Reorder columns
reordered_dataset1 <- dataset1[, c(2, 1)]

# See that rbind() is robust to column ordering
rbind(reordered_dataset1, dataset2)
```

In your workspace, there are two datasets called dataset1 and dataset2 you saw above. Try reordering the columns of dataset1. Call `rbind()` on dataset1 and dataset2 as well as reordered_dataset1 and dataset2.